# How to implement Google Maps API (initMap) in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, google-maps

I try to integrate Google Maps in Angular.

**index.html**

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=api_key&callback=initMap"></script>
```

**example.component.html**

```
...
<div id="map"></div>
...
```

**example.component.ts**

```
...
ngAfterViewInit() {
        function initMap() {
            var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 4,
                center: uluru
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: uluru,
                map: map
            });
        }
    }
```

I got still the error "initMap is not a function".

Answer (score 1):

It breaks because `initMap` function is not available when Google's script tries to call it. It's also not globally available as Google' script expects (it's scoped to the class).

There's an existing library called [Angular Google Maps](https://angular-maps.com/) whose purpose is using Google Maps with Angular applications.

Comment: I understood that AGM was primarily  for simple use cases and for more difficult application that installing the javascript version was prefered ??

Answer (score 0):

After looking arround for other solutions I ended up using Angular Google Maps `npm` module

Using these steps it help me to get started - https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/ - map is showing perfect.

**Steps:**

```
npm install @agm/core
```

In the `app.module.ts` add this:

```
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core'

//on imports section
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
  apiKey: 'YOUR_Maps_JavaScript_API_KEY_HERE'
})
```

In the component (`.ts`) that you want to show the map do this :

```
lat : number;
lng : number;

ngOnInit() {
    this.prepareMap() ;
}

prepareMap() {
    this.lat = 51.678418;
    this.lng = 7.809007;

    console.log("prepareDivMap finished");
}
```

in the corresponding `.css` file add this:

```
agm-map {
    height: 300px;
}
```

in the corresponding `html` part add this:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
    <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

An here is the result of google maps embedded into a angular component using agm

[image]